# Bluetooth and 2.4GHz wireless audio interference

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones, interference

I just bought a set of Turtle Beach PX5 headphones, which use the 2.404-2.476GHz spectrum for multichannel audio output, and Bluetooth for audio input. The sound is great until I start using the Bluetooth mic, which creates crackling and popping sounds in the headphones. The headphones' spec doesn't specify the Bluetooth version, but it does support A2DP. I have a cheap Bluetooth mini-dongle, but again I don't know what version of the spec it uses.

Is there some way to separate the bandwidth these devices use, to avoid interference?

Comment: Have you tried it on another machine?

Comment: I installed the Toshiba Bluetooth stack, and it seems to have improved slightly. Still no way to enable/disable Adaptive Frequency Hopping, which could be causing it.